# bootstrap-datetimepicker v4 not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

This problem is driving me crazy. I've been all day and it must be a stupid thing but I'm not able to find it...

The problem is simple, I followed the tutorial of bootstrap-datatimepicker but I cannot archieve it. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>title</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- external javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- datetimepicker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Im getting two errors in the Firebug.
First:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Second:

```
TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
```

If think the problem could be in the bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js because if I delete the line where it is I don't get the First error.
I tried loading scripts everywhere else, nothing happend.
I tried downloading the lastest version of ALL the libraries, nothing happend.
The control doesn't shows up no matter what I do.
Definitly I don't understand what is happening...
Really, I'm about to kill myself -.-u

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure all js scripts can be loaded? Do you see the script content when you try to load them in your browser? I think that bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js can not be found and gives a 404.

Comment: I also noticed that your script paths start with `js/...` and `css/...`. That means that if you load `http://www.domain.com/`, scripts are loaded from `http://www.domain.com/js/...`. But if you load `http://www.domain.com/page/`, scripts are loaded from `http://www.domain.com/page/js/...`. Make sure your paths start with a `/`.

Comment: I think `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js` cant load and this is why is given me the first error but I downloaded it from the homepage and it has like 2 months so in case this is a bad file people could complain long time ago!

Comment: Well time to check for 404's then... What URL is your page on?

Comment: I checked and they are loading, if they can't load if would appear in red at the Firebug. 
My page is not public yet :/ It's basically `localhost/charisma/date.html` and it only has the code I gave here.

Comment: Question: Have you updated moment.js or the bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js or jquery file recently?

Comment: And when you replace the datetimepicker js file with `https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/d004434a5ff76e7b97c8b07c01f34ca69e635d97/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`?

Comment: I'm using the lastest version of everything because I tried with older versions and fail too.

Comment: I cant get nothing from this link redelschaap, it's 404.

I found a bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js that works but is not doing very well. I think it cannot load the css now...

Maybe the problem is in the versions? my god...

Comment: Ok, I got this js redelschaap and its working, like the other! the problem now is the css, is not getting it but I think this is another battle =)

Answer (score 0):

I found it! I'm so sorry but I downloaded wrong the css and the js from github!!!
Turns out that I saved the link as .html and then I renamed it as .js (yes, now I see how dumb is it!)

I downloaded again but right and all problems are gone!

Thank you for putting me on the way!